# Error occur during Angular CLI installation

Tags: angular, io, angular-cli

I tried this with different solutions all day. But still the same error occurs. My `npm version is 5.3.0` and `node version is 8.5.0`.
When I type

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

and enter, these errors occur. I already tried recommended version( which may be older than this version) from node.js but it also occur difference errors which might worse than this. I think this node.js version is the latest. I follow the way from Angular io quickstack but it cannot be help me to solve this.   How can I solve this?

```
C:\Users\Lenovo>npm -v
5.3.0

C:\Users\Lenovo>node -v
v8.5.0

C:\Users\Lenovo>npm install -g @angular/cli

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOENT registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

```
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-18T13_28_55_949Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Do you have a proxy running ? You might need to configure your NPM to let it know about proxy configuration

Comment: Maybe post your debug log somewhere accessible on the web and place the link here?

Comment: Sorry, sir. I will try. Thank you.

Comment: Alex Beugnet, how can I know proxy is running?How to check it? I'm a new user for angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a proxy or VPN running. Then try uninstalling clearing your cache first `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` `npm cache clean` `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: Actually, in newer versions of `npm`, you have to specify ``--force`` to `npm cache clean` to force clean the cache since it will show a warning.

Comment: Sir, I don't know I know how to check about proxy or VPN running and how to fix it? My friends can easily install node.js and angular cli easily. Only my computer occurs error.

Comment: On windows, `Win + S` and search for `configure proxy server  -> LAN settings`  make sure proxy server is unchecked.